# How manipulate fragment from controller?

Tags: sapui5

I have a View and his Controller.
I have also a fragment that I have instantiated and I associate it to my controller.
The view contains the button with `id=idButtonV` and the fragment have `id=idButtonF`.

If in controller I write `this.byId("idButtonV")` i receive a result (the button element), but if i write `this.byId("idButtonF")` the result is `undefined`.
Why...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your fragment contains content that is living on the static layer of UI5 e.g. a `sap.m.Dialog`.

Therefore it's ids are not prefixed with the associated views prefix and that is why you have to use `sap.ui.getCore().byId()` to reference it:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("idButtonF");
```

NOTE: That can easily lead to duplicate ID problems. So better prefix ids inside static fragments yourself e.g. `myCoolFragment-idButtonF`